# patch does not substitute target object but returns it correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, python-mock

When I invoke mock.patch I expect it to replace the **type** I am replacing with the type I provided using the new keyword argument.
[It does not replace the type](https://travis-ci.org/testsuite/mockingbird/jobs/12184872) but it does return the correct object when `patch.start()` is invoked.
The `FakesPatcher` is a hack that forces the old object to create the new object. It works for [Python 3.x](https://travis-ci.org/testsuite/mockingbird/jobs/12185414) and [PyPy](https://travis-ci.org/testsuite/mockingbird/jobs/12185418). <s>However, [it doesn't work for Python 2.x](https://travis-ci.org/testsuite/mockingbird/jobs/12185416).</s>(See edit below).
I want the `FakesPatcher` to go away anyway and use `mock.patch` instead.

What's am I doing wrong here and how can I fix it?

```
def substitute(obj, qualified_name, spec):
    testdouble = mock.patch(qualified_name, spec=spec, spec_set=True, new=obj)
    testdouble.attribute_name = qualified_name # Forces patch to use the extra patcher

    class FakesPatcher(object):
        """Ugly hack."""
        new = 1

        def _new(*args, **kwargs): 
            return obj.__new__(obj)

        def __enter__(self):
            self._old_new = spec.__new__
            spec.__new__ = self._new
            return obj

        def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
            spec.__new__ = self._old_new

    testdouble.additional_patchers.append(FakesPatcher())

    return testdouble


def fake(obj):
   """


   :rtype : mock._patch
   :param obj:
   """
    try:
        configuration = obj.Configuration()
    except AttributeError:
        raise TypeError('A fake testdouble must have a Configuration class.')

    try:
        spec = configuration.spec
    except AttributeError:
        raise TestDoubleConfigurationError('The type to be faked was not specified.')

    qualified_name = get_qualified_name(spec)

    attrs = dict(obj.__dict__)
    attrs.pop('Configuration')

    methods = get_missing_methods(spec, obj)
    for method in methods:
        def make_default_implementation(attr):
            def default_implementation(*args, **kwargs):
                raise NotImplementedError('%s was not implemented when the object was faked.' % attr)

            return default_implementation

        attrs.update({method: make_default_implementation(method)})

    properties = get_missing_properties(spec, obj)
    for prop in properties:
        def make_default_implementation(attr):
            def default_implementation(*args, **kwargs):
                raise NotImplementedError('%s was not implemented when the object was faked.' % attr)

            return property(fget=lambda *args, **kwargs: default_implementation(*args, **kwargs),
                            fset=lambda *args, **kwargs: default_implementation(*args, **kwargs),
                            fdel=lambda *args, **kwargs: default_implementation(*args, **kwargs))

        attrs.update({prop: make_default_implementation(prop)})

    fake_qualified_name = get_qualified_name(obj)
    obj = type(obj.__name__, obj.__bases__, attrs)

    return substitute(obj, qualified_name, spec)
```

In case you want to play with the code and test it you can find it [here](https://github.com/testsuite/mockingbird/tree/master/mockingbird).

EDIT:
I [solved](https://travis-ci.org/testsuite/mockingbird/jobs/12193083) the Python 2.x errors by replacing the lambda with an instance method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your tests, if you want to use `mock.patch` in a `with` statement, the mock library requires you that you use the  return value of the patch as the mock object. Your test now become

```
    @it.should('replace the original methods with the fake methods')
    def test_should_replace_the_original_methods_with_the_fake_methods(case):
        class FakeObject(object):
            class Configuration(object):
                spec = RealObject

            def was_faked(self):
                return True

        with fake(FakeObject) as realObject:
            fake_obj = realObject()

            case.assertTrue(fake_obj.was_faked())
```

You can then use the following substitute or even get rid of it.

```
def substitute(obj, qualified_name, spec):
    return mock.patch(qualified_name, new=obj, spec=spec)
```

Patching works by patching types at the calling site. The following excerpt from the documentation is important.

> target should be a string in the form ‘package.module.ClassName’. The
>   target is imported and the specified object replaced with the new
>   object, so the target must be importable from the environment you are
>   calling patch from. The target is imported when the decorated function
>   is executed, not at decoration time.

If you want to patch the actual type, without using the return value with the `with` statement, you must not resolve the name of the class to a qualified name but local name.

The following changes

```
    @it.should('replace the original methods with the fake methods')
    def test_should_replace_the_original_methods_with_the_fake_methods(case):
       ...
    with fake(FakeObject, '%s.%s' % (__name__,'RealObject')):
        fake_obj = RealObject()

        case.assertTrue(fake_obj.was_faked())
```

**testdoubles__init__.py**

```
def fake(obj, qualified_name=None):
    """
    :rtype : mock._patch
    :param obj:
    """
    try:
        configuration = obj.Configuration()
    except AttributeError:
        raise TypeError('A fake testdouble must have a Configuration class.')

    try:
        spec = configuration.spec
    except AttributeError:
        raise TestDoubleConfigurationError('The type to be faked was not specified.')

    qualified_name = qualified_name or get_qualified_name(spec)
    ...
```

Now the problem is that you can't reliably find out where RealObject is coming from, at least I couldn't really find a way. You could assume that it is from the module where the calling function reside and do:

```
    qualified_name = "%s.%s" % (obj.__module__, spec.__name__)
```

Comment: What if I replace it globally?